# Steam across countries and accounts

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I am trying to give a laptop to family member in another country (he is mostly a gamer type, but the country's internet is too slow for massive downloads), and I want to give him some steam games downloaded from here. Dota 2, Team Fortress 2, etc.

But my questions are: 
If i download them on MY account (to the laptop), and he makes his account and logs in, does he have to re-download entirely, or will there be item problems, etc ?
And If I download games on a US connection logged into a US server, and he makes his in his country, will there be country problems in game.

If you need more info, I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless he owns the games, he'll have to purchase them again for his account, log into your account or be granted access using Steam's Family Sharing system.

Games like TF2 and DoTA 2 will work fine, but other titles such as Counter-Strike: GO will require a repurchase (for his account) or family sharing licenses.

As for having to download the games again, he does not have to. However, updates will be a different story.
Steam allows multiple accounts to access the same installed game (if they both own it or have a license via Family Sharing) if it's already downloaded.

---

As for being able to play the games depending on country, it depends on the country and the game.
Most games are available world-wide, but others (like Saints Row IV) have region-specific versions, which depends on the account's store country at the time of purchase.

For example, if you're shipping from US to Australia (or Russia), there won't be any issues.
But, shipping from Russia to US with a Russian Steam account is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Games that are free to play, such as TF2 and Dota 2, like you mentioned, will work fine, and the person who logs into his Steam account on the computer with the game won't have to re-download the game.

Games that are not free to play can only be accessed only if the account that owns that game is logged into in Steam. If Family Sharing is enabled and both of your accounts are linked together, while only one account can have access to said shared games at a time, as long as it is installed on the computer previously, the other account linked has no need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer provided by aytimothy.

It is best for you to download the games that you want to give on your laptop and create back up of all the games on the same machine.

Regardless of using your account or his own, he can restore the backed up games and be able to enjoy it at earliest. Do check if the games you are giving is available in your family member's region.

Happy gaming!

Comment: Backing up a game is only used for transferring games to another computer. Also, even if he restored them, he can't use them (if it's a paid game that he/she doesn't own).

Comment: Sure. But OP has not stated if he is planning to give the laptop with an account already logged in. So making a backup of all the games will make sure that the receiver will be able to get the files of the game as well. The backup can also serve the purpose of installing it on another machine, which is an added advantage.